# Print byte[] to PDF using PDFBox

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, pdfbox

I have a question about writing image to PDF using PDFBox.

My requirement is very simple: I get an image from a web service using Spring `RestTemplate`, I store it in a `byte[]` variable, but I need to draw the image into a PDF document.

I know that the following is provided:

```
final byte[] image = this.restTemplate.getForObject(
        this.imagesUrl + cableReference + this.format,
        byte[].class
);
```

`JPEGFactory.createFromStream()` for JPEG format, `CCITTFactory.createFromFile()` for TIFF images, `LosslessFactory.createFromImage()` if starting with buffered images. But I don't know what to use, as the only information I know about those images is that they are in THUMBNAIL format and I don't know how to convert from `byte[]` to those formats.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This applies to version 2.0, not to 1.8)

I don't know what you mean with THUMBNAIL format, but give this a try:

```
    final byte[] image = ... // your code
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
    BufferedImage bim = ImageIO.read(bais);
    PDImageXObject pdImage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc, bim);
```

It might be possible to create a more advanced solution by using

```
PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent()
```

but this one uses a file and not a stream, so it would be slower (but produce the best possible image type).

To add this image to your PDF, use this code:

```
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    try
    {
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);

        PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

        // draw the image at full size at (x=20, y=20)
        contents.drawImage(pdImage, 20, 20);

        // to draw the image at half size at (x=20, y=20) use
        // contents.drawImage(pdImage, 20, 20, pdImage.getWidth() / 2, pdImage.getHeight() / 2);

        contents.close();
        doc.save(pdfPath);
    }
    finally
    {
        doc.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually after testing an javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported Image Type is thrown at this line : **BufferedImage bim = ImageIO.read(bais);**

Comment: @saadoune Can you save the image byte array to a file? FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(....)); fos.write(array); fos.close(); and then open that file with IrfanView when press "I" (I like Information). What type is it?

Comment: When opening the image it shows a warning saying that it is a JPG file with incorrect extension but, in the help it says "compression : JPEG, CMYK, quality: 100, subsampling OFF". Thank you.

Comment: Ouch, CMYK Jpegs are indeed a problem for java ImageIO. What you could try is to use https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys , i.e. put the libraries for JPEG in your classpath.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help and indications, i have now added twelvemokeyproject to my workspace, and image-jpeg as a dependency, anyway, how am i supposed to use (read/write) methods from his  packages. Thanks again.

Comment: You don't have to change any code. It is just important that the twelvemonkeys jar files are your classpath. You can still use ImageIO.read(). (See "Basic usage" in the link)

Comment: Unfortunately i still have the javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported Image Type, image-jpeg is in the classpath and no changes to the code.

Comment: You need not one, but six jar files: twelvemonkeys-common-lang-3.2.1.jar
twelvemonkeys-common-io-3.2.1.jar
twelvemonkeys-common-image-3.2.1.jar
twelvemonkeys-imageio-core-3.2.1.jar
twelvemonkeys-imageio-metadata-3.2.1.jar
twelvemonkeys-imageio-jpeg-3.2.1.jar

Comment: Indeed, that's the case, they are inportet when setting imageio-jpeg as a dependency. But still not working.

Comment: Either it isn't in your classpath, or you've found a bug in twelvemonkeys. Can you share the file? If yes, please upload it somewhere. To verify that the JPEG plugin is installed and used at run-time, you could use the following code:

Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("JPEG");
while (readers.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("reader: " + readers.next());
}

The first line should print:

reader: com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader@somehash